# factory_girl (4.2.0) many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tdd, factory-bot

I want to properly establish a many-to-many factory set using FactoryGirl 4.2.0. I keep running into documentation/examples with outdated syntax from previous FactoryGirl versions mixed together and it just isn't working for me.

How do I set up this scenario given the following two resources and their linking table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_registrations
  has_many :registrations, through: :user_registrations
end

class UserRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :registration
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_registrations
  has_many :users, through: :user_registrations
end
```

This is what I have so far, as per the documentation [found here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations). This is as close as I've come so far into any real progress.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :registration do
    user
  end

  factory :user, class: User do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    password "password"

    factory :user_with_registrations do

      ignore do
        registrations_count 1
      end

      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        registrations FactoryGirl.create_list(:registration, evaluator.registrations_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which fails in the following manner, which I realize is because this setup is stated to be for a one-to-many relationship.

```
1) User Login Success
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_registrations)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user=' for #<Registration:0x007fc48e2ca768>
     # ./spec/factories.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the correct way to define a factory set for the many-to-many scenario using the latest FactoryGirl syntax? (4.2.0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it lookes like you have to make the `has_many` associations for `Registrations` and `Users` through `UserRegistrations`. This would then look like

```
    factory :user_registration do
       association :user
       association :registration
    end

    factory :user do
       ..setup for email and password

       factory :user_with_registrations do

          ignore do
            registrations_count 1
          end

          after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
            FactoryGirl.create_list(:user_registration, evaluator.registrations_count, user: user)
          end
       end
    end

    factory :registration do
       ..setup for registration

       factory :registration_with_user do

          ignore do
            users_count 1
          end

          after(:create) do |registration, evaluator|
            FactoryGirl.create_list(:user_registration, evaluator.users_count, registration: registration)
          end
       end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!
FYI: I've decided to go with Fabricator for my factory testing needs. Seems cleaner to me and I've already converted everything over. I'll probably use factory_girl in a future app to test the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran through this before, and the problem (less than obvious you'll agree on that) it that you use a constant name in your factory definitions.

Try to use a string instead, like this:

```
factory :user, class: 'User' do
  ...
```

Comment: Nope. Either way it still responds the same.